# f(n) from sequence?

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series

I'm more than a little rusty on my algebra and am realizing it could serve a great purpose here. I am currently trying to reverse engineer a relatively simple sequence of numbers but am having a hard time with it. This is the sequence:

500
490
481
472
464
456
448
441
434
427
420
414
408
402
396
390
385
380
375
370
365
360
356
352
348
344
340
336
332
329
326
323
320
317
314
311
308
306
304
302
300
298
296
294
292
290
289
288
287
286
285
284
283
282
281

I've determined that the difference decreases by 1 on a decreasing frequency. That frequency is:

-10
-9
-9
-8
-8
-8
-7
-7
-7
-7
-6
-6
-6
-6
-6
-5
-5
-5
-5
-5
-5
-4
-4
-4
-4
-4
-4
-4
-3
-3
-3
-3
-3
-3
-3
-3
-2
-2
-2
-2
-2
-2
-2
-2
-2
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1

That's where I'm getting stuck -- figuring out how to turn this into a function... I've been led to polynomials. Am I on the right track?

Comment: If these values were given by a polynomial of degree $n$, then repeating the "take differences of successive terms" $n$ times would result in a constant sequence.  This is not the case here for any reasonably small value of $n$, so you're not going to be able to fit a polynomial to the data in a useful way.

Comment: The current answers are all a bit theoretical. The answer you need may depend on exactly what you're doing. Why do you need a function to represent your sequence? Also, does the sequence continue infinitely, or is the list you have there the full sequence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your initial term corresponds to $n=0$  then you might find that

$$500 - 11n + n\left[\sqrt{2n}\right] + \frac{\left[\sqrt{2n}\right]-\left[\sqrt{2n}\right]^3}{6}$$  where $[x]$ is the nearest integer to $x$, fits your sequence rather more neatly than a $54$-degree polynomial.

This is related to [OEIS A060432](http://oeis.org/A060432)

Comment: Henry: YES! I had to round down to get the integer I was after. This is what the finished product looks like:

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/Cfzx3/)

Comment: Your code did the rounding at the end; my expression does it inside

Answer (score 1):

A function is just a *mapping* from one collection (input set)
of objects to another (output set). That is, for each $n$ in the
input set, you can associate it with an object $m$ in the output
set (this is written $f\left(n\right)=m$).

In your case, you have 55 elements in your sequence. What you have
done is entirely valid: you have **already** defined the function
$$
f\colon\underbrace{\left\{ 1,2,\ldots,55\right\} }_{\text{Input set}}\rightarrow\underbrace{\mathbb{Z}}_{\text{Output set}}.
$$
Here, the symbol $\mathbb{Z}$ means the set of all integers (i.e.
whole numbers, like 500, or 490). For example, $f\left(1\right)=281$,
$f\left(2\right)=282$, etc..

Perhaps more useful is the notion of a recurrence relation: an equation
that recursively defines a sequence. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation.
However, in this case, I do not think you'll have an easy time finding
a compact expression for the corresponding recurrence, and the verbal
description is probably best.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with the answer given by par.

One thing I might add--
Anytime the difference between successive terms in a sequence is constant, then that sequence can be represented by a linear function (i.e. a polynomial of degree 1). So it is possible to represent your sequence by 10 piecewise-defined linear functions. But, this is a cumbersome representation, and, as par has already said, your verbal description is probably best.